# Changing Table of Content Format

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using the book document class, and have parts, chapters, and sections.

I set the tableofcontents to show just parts and chapters:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

However, now the TOC has large spacing between all the items, and everything is bold.

Ideally, I would like the formatting to be similar to the default behaviour when there are chapters and sections.

The default behavior is:

Chapters bold and spaced; sections normal and close together.

I'd like:

Parts bold and spaced; chapters normal and close together.

Comment: You're request deliberately depends on the document class and perhaps which packages are used -- you provided no information on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\makeatletter
\let\l@part\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline {0}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{I should create MWEs}
\chapter{In the future I'll provide a MWE}
\chapter{I promise to provide MWEs when I ask on TeX.SX}
\part{I really should create MWEs}
\chapter{In the future I'll provide a MWE}
\chapter{I promise to provide MWEs when I ask on TeX.SX}
\part{I will accept answers}
\chapter{I will upvote answers}
\end{document}
```

Explanation: The macros responsible for typesetting the ToC are all of the form layer name prefixed with `\l@`. To put it simple `\let` changes the definition of the first macro-name to the second's. And `\@dottedtocline` is the macro responsible for typesetting those dotted ToC lines. The first argument is the tocdepth (chapter is 0) the other two are indents.

Comment: You forgot: `\part{I will accept answers}` and `\chapter{I will upvote answers}` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer edit is on the way, thanks for reminding!

Comment: That worked perfectly. You've basically trained me not to use MWE. JK! Lesson learned...

Comment: @DrXorile that's because I'm more the forgiving type. And I hoped to brainwash you with the chapter and part names despite not waiting for a MWE. And the above might have failed badly if you used any package altering the toc.

Comment: In the spirit of learning, can you tell me what it actually does! Not that I'm above blindly taking snippets off the internet...

Comment: @DrXorile small explanation added.